# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq A \subset X$. Show that $f(x) = d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}$ is a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space and $\emptyset \neq A \subset X$. Show that $f(x) = d(x,A) = \inf\{d(x,a) : a \in A\}$ is a continuous function.

I found this question answered on this website already using the epsilon of room technique. I was wondering if we could prove this using the fact that for continuous functions on metric spaces we have that $(x_i) \rightarrow x$ implies $f(x_i) \rightarrow f(x) \iff f$ is continuous.

Help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the triangle inequality to show that $$|d(x,A)-d(y,A)|\le d(x,y),$$ then you can easily show continuity via sequences. (In fact, the above inequality means that $f$ is even Lipschitz-continuous.)

Comment: Care to spill a few more details for me?? :D

Comment: First of all, do you see how to proceed once you have shown this inequality?

Comment: Okay, I actually just showed the inequality. I'm not sure if it was was rigorous since I made the assumption that $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,A)$ which in my opinion is a pretty obvious generalization of the triangle inequality.

From there, suppose $(x_i) \rightarrow (x)$. Then we have that $|d(x_i,A) - d(x,A)| \leq d(x_i,x) \rightarrow 0$. Therefore $d(x_i,A) = f(x_i) \rightarrow f(x)$ and thus since our space is first countable (as a metric space) we have that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Right, that's the idea. However, the "pretty obvious generalization" can still be proved rigorously. Note that $d(x,A)\le d(x,a)\le d(x,y)+d(y,a)$ for all $a\in A$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: $d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,a)$. Now take the infimum over all $a \in A$ to get:

$d(x,A) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,A)$. Does that work?

Comment: Yes, it does. :-)